# Source that Gr"a finished the "whole" Torah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, agada-stories-legends, siyum, vilna-gaon

I heard from a friend that he read that the Vilna Gaon did a Sium on the Torah. Not just the חמישה חומשי תורה, but that he basically claimed that he finished all there is to learn in Jewish studies. Torah, Gemara, Kabala, etc.

Does anyone have a source to this? Is this a known thing?

Comment: What about things that came after he died?

Comment: @Daniel I have a feeling that that wasn't included in the sium

Comment: I'd be surprised to hear the contrary in as far as the learning, not the "siyum" per say. I wonder if this includes Chassidishe seforim, of which there were probably only a handful at that time? Chances are he read those too ;)

Comment: I've heard that the Gaon was able to take any law written in the Torah and bring up all the relevant oral law discussions (Shas) as well as the psak halacha.

Comment: @warz3 he might not have considered those "Torah"

Comment: @Daniel good point, although I think his issues with Chassidus boiled down to very complex interpretations of certain point(s) in the writings of the Arizal as well as misunderstandings of their practices which might only disqualify parts (if any) of their seforim and not the seforim in general, but I don't know exactly what his issues were and how he held.

Comment: see rabbi chaim volozhin's hakdama on the Gaon's commentary to sifrei ditzenuta. it's printed also in the foreword of vilna gaon on mishlei in some books

Comment: IMHO, this question sounds a bit silly. It's one thing to say that the Gra studied every major text that he was taught to believe was part of "the masorah", but it's another to suppose that he thought that he had thus "finished", in a sense, with Torah altogether - that Torah is a closed, bound system that one could actually do a siyum on, rather than something of infinite breadth and scope.

Comment: Did your friend give any indication of where he may have read this? Could he? Any information along those lines would make it easier to track this story down, if it's to be found somewhere other than in a recent conversation.

Comment: @Isaac Moses unfortunately no.. He doesn't remember where he read it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is brought in the [introduction to the Sefer Peat HaSulchan](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37666&st=&pgnum=7&hilite=). It says there that he learned and understood clearly all that there is to learn (until the Achronim on the Shulchan Aruch) including the Kisvei Arizal, and understood everything besides 2 Sugeot in the Zohar.

Comment: Which 2 Sugiyot?

Comment: Does your source say that the Gra himself said he finsihed everything or was it a disciple who said it ,big difference.